# Can't sign into iTunes on Mac 10.7.5

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, macos, apple-id

I can open the iTunes app and it seems to be working as normal, but whenever I try to sign in it gives me two error messages, one after the other.

- first - "We could not complete your iTunes Store request. An unknown error occurred(-50)."
- second presents immediately after dismissing the first - “ We could not complete your iTunes Store request. An unknown error occurred (-9836).”

I'm using an early 2008 Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 that is fully updated but not upgrades past Lion.

Is this a server issue or something with my Mac?

Comment: What exact model? See https://everymac.com/systems/by_year/macs-released-in-2008.html

Answer (score 0):

My answer:
Since you mention that you are running Mac OS X Lion (10.7.5), the issue could be that your operating system is no longer supported. Try to update your Mac and see if it works.

My experience:
I had a similar issue on Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9). Once I updated to Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11), the issue went away.

Comment: iTunes still works on Mavericks at least. I’d be a little surprised if Lion was cut off, given that stuff like the App Store still works.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Interesting. Mavericks didn’t quite work on my machine. I’ll edit my answer.